# Render a partial view based upon click event

Tags: c#, css, model-view-controller, razor

within my MVC application , I have many partial views which specific ones can only be displayed upon clicking an hyperlink.

Razor View : Index.Html

```
@Html.Partial("ViewSkills")
@Html.Partial("Skill_List")
```

Partial Code : Skill_List.cshtml

```
<div class="skill_list">
Some content here
</div>
```

Partial Code : ViewSkills.cshtml

```
<div class="View Skill">
<input type="button" id="viewskills" value="View Skills" /> 
</div>
```

CSS for skill_list

```
.skill_list {
display : none
}
```

I am aiming for the button with id viewskills to render the skill_list partial view when clicked upon?

I don't wish to use any Javascript , Jquery or Ajax . I am aiming to do this only using C# and CSHTML. Any ideas how?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax.BeginForm to insert/replace an element for retuned partial view html.

```
<div id="viewskills" class="skill_list">
Some content here
</div>

@using(Ajax.BeginForm("Viewskills", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "viewskills", HttpMethod = "Post" }))
{
     <div>
        <input type="submit" value="View Skills" id="btnViewSkills" />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this loads my partial view in a seperate page?